# How to call a function every x seconds but be able to do stuff in the meantime

Tags: c++, sleep, tetris

I'm building a tetris game and I need the pieces to fall every x seconds; something like:

```
while(true){
  moveDown();
  sleep(x)
}
```

The problem is, I need to be able to move the pieces left and right in the meantime, i.e., call a function while it's sleeping.

How can I do that in c++?

Comment: Did you try threads? Then you can run functions in parallel. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-in-cpp/

Comment: Note that you will have a similar problem problems getting keypresses in raw C++ as all of the Standard IO routines are blocking.

Comment: threading is what you need

Comment: I'm not sure threading is the right answer here. I keep thinking a synchronous system with non-blocking IO and a tick will work better for this in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solvable in multiple ways (another idea that comes to mind is [multithreading](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/), but that seems overkill). One approach would be to keep track of the number of "game cycles" and execute some function every n-th cycle like this:

```
for(int32_t count{1};;count++)
{
    if (!count % 5)
    {
        // do something every 5th cycle
    }
    // do something every cycle
    sleep(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both time and key presses can be events which can be used to wait on. On UNIXes you'd use something like `poll()` with a suitable time for timeout and the input device used to recognize key presses. On other systems there are similar facilities (I'm a UNIX persons and I have never worked on Windows specific stuff although it seems the Windows facilities are actually more flexible). Depending on the result of `poll()` (timeout or activity on the I/O device in that case) you'd do the appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

you can measure how much time has passed since last fall and move piece down after given amount and then reset counter. In pseudo-code it could look like this:

```
while(true)
{
    counter.update();
    if(counter.value() == fall_period)
    {
        move_piece_down();
        couter.reset();
    }
    // rotate pieces
}
```

If you are using typical implementation of game loop your counter can just accumulate elapsed time since last frame.